# What is wrong with this LINQ query?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I am trying to write a LINQ query against two objects ( `SPListItemCollection` and `List<SPListItem>`).

When my query is like the one below it works fine:

```
var licFirst = from n in navList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>()
               from z in licZeroth
               where ((SPFieldLookupValueCollection)n["Parent"]).Select(t=>t.LookupId).Contains(z.ID)
               select n;
```

When I add an item to the select:

```
var licFirst = from n in navList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>()
               from z in licZeroth
               where ((SPFieldLookupValueCollection)n["Parent"]).Select(t=>t.LookupId).Contains(z.ID)
               select n, ParentId = z.ID;
```

It begins to error out with:

> The name 'z' does not exist in the
>   current context

How can I select `z.ID`?

Comment: Did you mean `select new { Obj = n, ParentId = z.ID }`?

Comment: have you tried select new { n, ParentId = z.ID }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your second version, you need to change the syntax a little to get an anonymous type with 2 properties, the `n` and the `ParentID`.

```
select new { n, ParentID = z.ID };
```

If this is not what you want, please clarify in the question.

Answer (score 0):

your final query should be this one

```
var licFirst = from n in navList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>()
           from z in licZeroth
           where ((SPFieldLookupValueCollection)n["Parent"]).Select(t=>t.LookupId).Contains(z.ID)
           select new { n, ParentId = z.ID };
```